# My List Item Menus are all now Compressed, used to be expanded by default

Tags: menu-item

No one else is seeing their items this way, so obviously I've changed something somewhere. When I click on an item, I want all of the menus to be expanded on the ribbon
[image]

Comment: i've seen that behavior in the past, i had to close ctrl + F5, close my browser , open the browser again, and be sure that my browser is expended before browsing into sharepoint. 

sometimes it works.. sometimes it doesn't

Comment: Try changing the browser's Zoom level, from the menus or by using CTRL and the mouse wheel. Have you made any customizations that impact the ribbon? (Custom features, JavaScript, etc.)

Comment: YES!!!! Thank you, Mike Smith!!! My zoom was set to 90%....I feel so stupid lol